# How to resize Dialog window in mfc in vs 2010?

Tags: mfc, dialog

I looked for many code. All of them says of replacing "CDialog" class with user defined class. But the problem is, I have many other functions and member variable definition in Dialog that I can't omit, otherwise my application window functionality will be gone.

Comment: Search "cdialog resizeable" on google, there are tons of code and information out there.

Comment: What you read probably stated to "derive" your own class from CDialog which you must already be doing.  Not sure why this would present a problem.  You should follow Michael Walz advice.

Comment: They don't say replace, they probably want you to derive your class from yours which is in turn derived from CDialog. This will give your dialog resizing capability.

Comment: They say to derive it..but they also say to replace The occurrence of CDialog class with my user defined class.